# What was "baptism" to the Jews in the time of John the Baptist?

Tags: history, christianity

Did Jews before John the Baptist practice something called "baptism"?  If so, what was it and what was its significance?  I am looking for a traditional Jewish understanding of this concept in its historical context.

I understand that John the Baptist was a Jewish priest and perhaps an Essene which was a Jewish sect, and that he was also considered a Prophet by the Jewish people of his time.  This makes me think that Judaism might have something to say about baptism.

Comment: Can you define "baptism"?

Comment: IINM (though I know very little about it) the definition of "baptism" is up for some very heated debate even among Christians. I really don't think readers of this site can be expected to know what it means. I move to close as "unclear what you're asking". cc @DoubleAA

Comment: Baptism is not a Christian word.  John the Baptist was a Jewish priest and perhaps an Essenes which was a Jewish sect.  John the Baptist was also considered a Prophet by the Jewish people of his time.  My question is specifically related to asking about the traditional meaning from oral or written history of the Jews.  I want Jewish scholars to tell me the history and meaning of Baptism.

Comment: @AdamHeeg thanks for the edit.  I've made a further edit to focus on the question "what was baptism in this historical context?" and reopened.  I couldn't figure out how the part about repentance and ashes was connected so I removed that; please feel free to [edit] that back in if you can clarify it. (You can see the revision history by clicking on the "edited" link above my name.)  Thanks.

Comment: @Adam Heeg - "baptism" is not a translation of "mikveh". Certainly not. And, yes, "baptism" is essentially a Christian word. And if you don't know much about Jewish history, then how can you be confident that John the Baptist was a historical character that was considered anything by Jews in his time, let alone a prophet? You are simply assuming the truth of the New Testament. John the Baptist is only mentioned in the Gospel narratives and in Josephus (a book that has been modified greatly by Christian redactors and censors). And herein lies the problem...

Comment: ...with your question. You are asking a question that essentially assumes a certain answer and requires Jews to give ascent to the distinct historicity and reliability of the gospels to communicate accurate biographical information. Further, to understand "baptism" in its historical context, you would have to study a large amount of textual material. My suggestion is that you read up on Jewish history and practices and then eventually this question will become irrelevant because it will answer itself quite easily.

Comment: We (Jews) don't know what a 'baptism' is that we should know if Jews did anything like it at the time. The fact that the Christian gospels claim Jews did it then doesn't help us much as we don't ascribe a huge amount of reliability to those texts. Please define, as I asked you above, what process exactly you want to know about and use words that we can understand.

Comment: Well, I accept you don't know what baptism is or have studied it, and perhaps you are right it is only Christian and only in Christian texts.  However, it is possible that another person may have studied it and found it in historical Jewish text or heard it in oral tradition.  Before you assume everyone only knows what you know about Jewish history maybe you should see what others have to say.  Just because you don't know of an answer doesn't mean there isn't one.

Comment: You may be right, but I find it very presumptuous and judgmental on your part to assume NO person has heard of it in any context other than Christian.  Ironically there was no such thing as a Christian in the context of my question and the origin of the word.

Comment: @AdamHeeg So you will not accept the answer of "no" to this question? Then it's not really a question.

Comment: @Daniel Questions whose answers are "no" are still questions. They just have answers of a particular form.

Comment: @DoubleAA, right, but I think Daniel meant that a yes/no question whose asker will accept only a "yes" to is not a question but a rhetorical device.

Comment: I'm not aware of any Jewish sources that ascribe any special status to John the Baptist.  (I've certainly never heard the claim *from Jews* that he was a prophet.)  If you know of sources that say that, citing them in your question would strengthen it, if that part is important to your question.

Comment: Assuming there was such a person, he MIGHT have been a Kohen responsible for administering the ashes of the Para Aduma to make someone tahor after tumas meis. We don't however know, but that task does involve water sprinkling

Comment: @AdamHeeg The comments here are just asking you to define what baptism is so we can answer the question. You responded by saying, "Baptism is not a Christian word. John the Baptist was a Jewish priest and perhaps an Essenes which was a Jewish sect. John the Baptist was also considered a Prophet by the Jewish people of his time." There is push-back because you make this unsubstantiated (and likely untrue) statement and seem to be implying that we should just know what it means, so you're unwilling to define the term.

Comment: @Daniel Please forgive me for not realizing my study of Jewish history was as inadequate as it appears to be.  I know comparatively little of Jewish history, however I thought that certain things I've been taught or learned as part of Jewish history were accepted by others as Jewish history.  If nothing else I've learned that is not the case.  I understand how frustrating it can be to have someone tell you your history which in fact is not accepted as such.  My mistake was one of ignorance, I apologize.

Comment: @AdamHeeg I'm sorry this has been so frustrating for all involved.  Unfortunately, Christians sometimes assert things about Judaism and Jewish history that just aren't true (their theology relies on doing so).  I don't think the claims about who JtB is are really germane to your question anyway; what we really need is to know what *you mean* (or what you think he meant, if you prefer) by "baptism".  I'm going to put this on hold pending that clarification; if you edit that in we can review for reopening.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Jews practiced something that in English would be called Baptism before John the Baptist. However, there were many different groups who viewed it in different ways.

The laws for baptism (which i will henceforth call immersion) had to do with ritual purity. It's hard for us to grasp how much purity mattered to Jews/Israelites in times of yore since we no longer have a temple. But just to give a small illustration, if you were a woman, and you flipped out and stabbed someone, and they escaped but died on the road, you could still go to the temple and stand before God because while you had sinned, you were not ritually impure. But a woman on her period? She is unfit to stand before God.

The rules and laws of immersion as set forth in the Bible all had to do with purity. Whether it was contact with corpses, seminal emissions, sex, leprosy, etc etc. But after the Jews returned from captivity, you started seeing new and innovative religious innovations. People could go to Synagogue rather than the temple to learn, people were encouraged to learn to read and write for themselves, to take on small traditions that usually only the priests did (like washing ritually before eating). And there started cropping up different views of immersion, and just how certain actions could make you impure such as sex, perhaps also sins caused spiritual impurity, and therefore getting immersed could clean you of those impurities as well.

In terms of the specifics, who did what, and how long. Most of that information has been lost. But we do know that people were doing it, and for lots of different reasons. From a historical perspective, it would be a fair statement to say that out of all the others doing immersion during that time, John was probably the most popular, and also why the New Testament probably mentions him so much. If John was famous in that contemporary time, to write and say that he was on your religious side would be a good advantage for spreading your message.

Comment: I really don't think the OP is talking about mikveh. He mentions atonement for sin, which the mikveh doesn't directly have anything to do with.

Comment: @Daniel Jews no longer practice Baptism for atonement of sin, but historically there were Jews who did so. But we only have vague snippets from them. Just like we know there were Jews who believed in a solar calendar, that the days started with sunrise rather than sunset, and thought the priesthood was evil. All of these notions have fallen off for contemporary Judaism, but they all very much existed at some point

Comment: @Aaron re your answer and your comment: Asking what Jews do/did, unrelated to Judaism, is off-topic on this site, so the only reasonable interpretation of the question above is as asking what Judaism does/did, unless the question includes some explanation tying "baptism" to Judaism (which it does not).

Comment: @msh210 Asking what observant Jews did as part of historical Judaism sounds pretty on topic to me. The fact that we modern religionists don't hold by that anymore doesn't change that to me. If someone asks did Jews ever believe that only the Talmud was binding, we can say yes via history! And that was valid Judaism, even though now only very few follow that belief

Comment: @Aaron no one said "observant" until you just did. And I already said (well, implied) that asking what Jews did as part of Judaism is on-topic. Asking what Jews did in general, however, is off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

> Did Jews before John the Baptist practice something called "baptism"?

No, Jews before that time spoke mostly Aramaic and, earlier, Hebrew. English as we know it didn't even exist until after Chaucer's time.

---

Nor did Judaism (at any time) include a practice **now** called "baptism" (if that's what you meant by your question). The word doesn't appear in any English-language work I've ever read (or talk I've heard) as a description of a practice of Judaism; and current dictionaries, in defining the term, make no reference to a practice of Judaism.

Comment: http://www.alanknox.net/2008/01/baptism-in-josephus/ though it's more of a verb there than a name of a ritual.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't see how that shows that **Judaism** includes something that people now call **"baptism"**. It shows only that (Josephus claims) **Jews** (and boats etc.) did something that he called **"βαπτίζω"**, and that wasn't the question, above. (The question did mention Jews, not Judaism, but if it really meant that then it's totally off-topic, so I'm interpreting it as meaning Judaism.)

Comment: This is incorrect. John the Baptist was a Jew and was considered a Jew by his contemporaries. His immersion ritual was not part of mainstream Judaism but it was part of his, and later Jesus's, and his followers branch of Judaism. That baptism is no longer practiced by Jews is beside the point.